# Undo/Redo for Collection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, undo-redo

I have a simple WPF screen with a `DataGrid` and some Buttons for Cut, Copy, Paste and Delete row(s):

[image]

I want to implement `Undo/Redo` functionality for all the operations like Cut/Copy/Paste/Add/Remove etc. I am open to use another collection controls instead of `DataGrid` if they provide some benefit over other. I have gone through some other questions on stackoverflow.com about the same topic but don't find them useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think this functionality is easiest implemented using special frameworks, they are generally not large and free. There are many frameworks that allow you to implement `Undo/Redo` functionality. Personally, I liked [`GuiLabs.Undo`](http://undo.codeplex.com), he is one of the simplest and most comfortable which I've have used. The whole point of the work is in [`action`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/06/29/new-codeplex-project-a-simple-undo-redo-framework.aspx):

> Every Action encapsulates a change to your domain model. The process of preparing the Action is explicitly separated from executing it. The execution of an action might come at a much later stage after it's been prepared and scheduled. Any Action implements `IAction` and essentially provides two methods: one for actually doing the stuff, and another for undoing it.

The most important thing is to create a class of *AbstractAction* interface and save it in the right place. You have to be using `ActionManager` to keep the Action that you want to Undo in the future:

```
private void SomeActionLogic()
{
    MyAction action = new MyAction(parameter);
    actionManager.RecordAction(action);
}
```

Then in somewhere using `Undo/Redo`:

```
actionManager.Undo();
...
actionManager.Redo();
```

So do you need to consider how you will work with a collection in the `AbstractAction` class? Maybe it will be labor-intensive on resources, because every time when triggered `Undo/Redo` is necessary to address a collection.

Simple example of using, taken from [`here`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/07/02/samples-for-the-undo-framework.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original color");

        SetConsoleColor(ConsoleColor.Green);
        Console.WriteLine("New color");

        actionManager.Undo();
        Console.WriteLine("Old color again");

        using (Transaction.Create(actionManager))
        {
            SetConsoleColor(ConsoleColor.Red); // you never see Red
            Console.WriteLine("Still didn't change to Red because of lazy evaluation");
            SetConsoleColor(ConsoleColor.Blue);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Changed two colors at once");

        actionManager.Undo();
        Console.WriteLine("Back to original");

        actionManager.Redo();
        Console.WriteLine("Blue again");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void SetConsoleColor(ConsoleColor color)
    {
        SetConsoleColorAction action = new SetConsoleColorAction(color);
        actionManager.RecordAction(action);
    }

    static ActionManager actionManager = new ActionManager();
}

class SetConsoleColorAction : AbstractAction
{
    public SetConsoleColorAction(ConsoleColor newColor)
    {
        color = newColor;
    }

    ConsoleColor color;
    ConsoleColor oldColor;

    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    }

    protected override void UnExecuteCore()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MegaMind: My answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the [Command Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25445/WPF-Command-Pattern-Applied)

With this pattern, every action has a counter action(redo/undo). You hold your applied and undone commands in stacks. This will allow you to undo and redo all commands. WPF is great for this thing, as you can bind commands directly to your elements, instead of ordinary events.